# Is there an easy way to generate website demos?

Tags: html, website

I am looking for a record and playback framework that records my interactions with the site to generate a help site with step by step screenshots and instructions based on clicks.
I want an easy to use tool that can generate decent demo pages that I can edit without much effort.
Is there something already available?

I don't think it matters but the website is a done in spring, jsp, jquery.

Comment: Just use of of the existing screen recording applications like camtasia.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool called [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) that takes screen cams of what you do on a site and saves them as Flash files. (I think it can output other types of video as well)

It's got a ton of other features, but all I ever needed was the screencam feature.